# How to send a lexicon to text-to-speech

Tags: python, azure

I'd like help with incorporating a new lexicon into the Azure Text-to-Speech API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/speech-technologies/hh378492%28v%3doffice.14%29

I've successfully sent text and have gotten mp3 files that work. Now I'm trying to incorporate a lexicon with difficult pronunciations.

I'm using the Python SDK for Text-to-Speech and have few questions from the documentation.

- Is this reference 'lexicon Element SSML (Microsoft.Speech)' outdated?
- What URI do I use?
- When I use the instructions in this document, I get the following error message: Status code: 400. Something went wrong. Check your subscription key and headers. How do I fix or investigate this?
- What format does the lexicon have to be in? I saw an example in the document that referenced a lexicon in a .pls format. How do I create this? Here is the reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<speak
version="1.0"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis"
xml:lang="en-US">
<lexicon
uri="c:\Test\whatchamacallit.pls"
type="application/pls+xml"/>
 Gimme the whatchamacallit. </speak>
```

Here's part of the Python that I'm using:

```
xml_body = ElementTree.Element('speak', version='1.0')
xml_body.set('{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang', 'en-us')
lexicon = ElementTree.SubElement(xml_body, 'lexicon')
lexicon.set('uri', '/User/.../Desktop/MedLex.pls')
lexicon.set('type', 'application/pls+xml')
```